# Why Lorenz attractor can be embedded by a 3-step time delay map?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, chaos-theory

I'm investigating attractor reconstruction of Lorenz system. I saw a bunch of work claiming that the time delay map $[x(t), x(t -\tau), x(t - 2\tau)]$ is sufficient to reconstruct the attracotr, e.g. http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Attractor_reconstruction,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6i57udsPKms.

If I'm understanding this correctly, this means that the state space of Lorenz system can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$. However as far as I have known by Takens' theorem, the time delay step $n$ to embed a strange attractor of dimension $d$ should be $n \geq 2d+1$. In this sense, since the fractal dimension of Lorenz attractor is slightly greater than $2$, there should be at least $5$ delay steps in order to achieve the embedding.

Is there any specific theorem/paper claiming that the Lorenz attractor can be embedded by a 3-step time delay embedding?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Great post! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will hep you understand how best to form questions and answers.

Comment: The theorem gives a guarantee for $n\ge 2d+1$, but does not claim that smaller $n$ do not work. // The similar image is for $τ=0.1$, just doubling it to $τ=0.2$ gives a much curvier surface.

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the reply! I understand that Takens' theorem only provides an upper limit. What I'm concerned is that $[x(t), x(t-\tau), x(t-2\tau)]$ does not seem to be an embedding since I could not find any rigorous theorem says so. Do you happen to now any reference?

Comment: No, only the argument put forward in the answer that the system is sufficiently coupled that the map from $[x(t),y(t),z(t)]$ to the states at $t−τ$ and $t-2τ$ and then projecting down to $[x(t),x(t−τ),x(t−2τ)]$ is bijective, so that the dynamics is faithfully captured in the 3-step delay map. // When plotting, it helps much for smaller $τ$ to apply a linear transformation and plot the curve [(x(t)+x(t−τ)+x(t−2τ)),(x(t)-x(t−2τ)),(x(t)-2x(t−τ)+x(t−2τ))]$.

Answer (score 1):

> this means that the state space of Lorenz system can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Without a restriction to delay embedding, this is trivial since the Lorenz system consists of three differential equations.

> However as far as I have known by Takens' theorem, the time-delay step $n$ to embed a strange attractor of dimension $d$ should be $n \geq 2d+1$.

The dimension given by Takens’s theorem is only an upper limit. A lower embedding dimension may suffice. Also see [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2262961/65502).

Also note that Takens’s theorem doesn’t use fractal dimensions at all; it’s the Sauer–Yorke–Casdagli theorem that does.

> Is there any specific theorem/paper claiming that the Lorenz attractor can be embedded by a 3-step time delay embedding?

Given that the Lorenz attractor can be embedded in three dimensions (see above), it would be intuitively surprising if a three-dimensional delay embedding fails here (in particular for all delays).
Moreover, and maybe most importantly, three-dimensional delay embeddings of the Lorenz attractor have been used extensively investigated for benchmarking, proofs of principle, or similar – which, to my knowledge, hasn’t turned up any inconsistencies as to be expected for a failed embedding.

I am not aware of rigorous investigations of this, but I wouldn’t be surprised if none exist, due to a lack of relevance: The entire point of a Takens embedding is to reconstruct attractors of unknown dynamics. Applying it to something like the Lorenz system is only for benchmarking, proofs of principle, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! By saying "Given that the Lorenz attractor can be embedded in three dimensions (see above), it would be surprising if a delay embedding fails here (in particular for all delays).", do you mean that since Lorenz attractor can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$, there must exist time delay embedding with $n\geq 7$? Actually I don't know whether $[x(t), x(t - \tau), x(t - 2\tau)]$ is an embedding since there is no theorem substantiate it. All existing work I've found assume this by default since trajectory of original system looks similar to time-delayed trajectory....

Comment: @mw19930312: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As to why 3 delay steps are sufficient for the Lorenz system:

We know that by Taylor
$$
\frac{x(t+τ)-x(t-τ)}{2τ}=\dot x(t)+\frac{τ^2}6\dddot x(t)+...
$$
and
$$
\frac{x(t+τ)-2x(t)+x(t-τ)}{τ^2}=\ddot x(t)+\frac{τ^2}{12}x^{(4)}(t)+...
$$
Now insert the Lorenz differential equations
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
\dot x&=σ(y-x)\\
\ddot x&=σ(x(\rho-z)-y-\dot x)
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies
\left.\begin{aligned}
y&=x+\frac{\dot x}σ\\
z&=\rho-\frac{y+\dot x+\frac{\ddot x}σ}{x}
\end{aligned}\right\}
$$
to see that up to order $τ^2$ the values of $y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are easy to extract from the difference quotients and the first derivative terms on the right.

[image]

<sub>*Reconstruction using above approximations and $\tau=0.03$. The reconstructed curve follows closely the original curve, except close to $x=0$ where the division-by-zero leads to singularities, even in a mollified division.*</sub>

Involving higher order derivative terms gives a system of higher degree that will provide a more exact relation between the two sets of data.
But even this first approximation shows that it is possible to invoke the inverse function theorem as long as $x\ne0$ to get a bijection.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!